# Gnome не сохраняет положение и размер окна

Tags: linux, archlinux, gnome

Если открыть окно, например gnome terminal изменить размер, переместить его и закрыть - не сохранится ни размер, ни положение.
GNOME Shell 3.34.2

Comment: Отредактируйте свой вопрос. Здесь язык общения - русский.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian. As follows from the name, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). This question may get closed soon, but if you choose to translate, it will surely be reopened, once the translation is done.

Comment: Так везде работает Gnome terminal - по дефолту. Если он закрывается, т.е. сессия закончена, по какой причине должно сохранятся исходное состояние? Или это где-то руцями дополнительно прописывалось? (в вопросе это не указано). Позиционирование можно выставить в настройках, там вроде ничего сложного.

Comment: @Anton Или сложность состоит в том как всё это настроить? Если так, то необходимо уточнение в вопросе. - "Как должно в результате распологаться окно gnome-терминала?" В такой формулировке вопрос могут закрыть (хотя не факт)

Comment: Для меня было было открытие, что размер не сохраняется, напостой делаю окно шире, казалось что сохраняет расширение, оказывается - просто не замечал, спасибо за ответ

Comment: В xfce точно есть опция - располагать все новые окна в центре экрана. В гноме тоже где-то должна быть, поищите. А размеры окна устанавливаются в настройках самого терминала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, оно и не должно помнить, просто не замечал раньше, т.к. окно в настройках шире сделал, и не увеличивал/уменьшал